# Problems with Log4net multiple logger to multiple files

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

log4net version: 1.2.13.0
Runtime Version: v4.0.30319

I've got some Problems with using multiple Loggers and Appenders.
I have a root Logger with 3 Appenders which work well but when im configuring multiple other loggers log4net seems to only register the appenders from the last logger specified in the app.config.

If i put TaskSyncLogger as last logger entry TaskSyncAppender gets recognized
If i put CalendarSyncLogger as last logger entry CalendarSyncLogger gets recognized

only the 3 appenders from the root logger and the appender from the last logger entry is listed in hierarchy.GetAppenders()

```
Hierarchy hierarchy = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
var appenders = hierarchy.GetAppenders();
```

my app.config

```
<appender name="MainFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger- %message%newline %exception" />
  </layout>
  <file value="Logs\logs.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" /> 
</appender>
<appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level - %message%newline %exception" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level - %message%newline %exception" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="TaskSyncAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <file value="Logs\logsTask.log" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger- %message%newline %exception" />
  </layout>
  <!--
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
  </filter>
  -->
</appender>

<appender name="CalendarSyncAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <file value="Logs\logsCalendar.log" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger- %message%newline %exception" />
  </layout>
  <!--
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
  </filter>
  -->
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="All" />
  <appender-ref ref="MainFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</root>

<logger Name="CalendarSyncLogger" additivity="true">
  <level value="All"/>
  <appender-ref ref="CalendarSyncAppender"/>
</logger>

<logger Name="TaskSyncLogger" additivity="true">
  <level value="All"/>
  <appender-ref ref="TaskSyncAppender"/>
</logger>
```

further the TaskSyncAppender isn't writing anything the File gets created but it remains empty although the the MainFile Appender is writing the output.

im getting it like

```
public const string TaskSyncLogger = "TaskSyncLogger";

private static readonly ILog logTask = LogManager.GetLogger(LoggingStrings.TaskSyncLogger);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this, and while I cannot be confident in saying it is definitely a bug, it is certainly unexpected.

You can work around it by adding this last logger to your file:

```
<logger Name="WillNotBeUsed">
  <level value="Off"/>
  <appender-ref ref="CalendarSyncAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="TaskSyncAppender"/>
</logger>
```

After that all five appenders are loaded.

Comment: thank you for your response.  Thats a creative way of solving this issue ;) but do you have any clue why the appenders aren't writing anything?

Comment: Well, if they aren't loaded, there will be no output?

Comment: the TaskAppender got loaded

Comment: When log files fail to get written but the config has been loaded, it's usually a permissions issue

Comment: The file gets created and the log file of the MainFileAppender is in the same directory

Comment: i tested to log to a different file with only 1 additional logger and it worked (i just removed CalendarSyncLogger) and it worked... seems like log4net really got a bug here. Anyway thank you for your help